# How to create task in a SP 2010 workflow and get the outcome?

Tags: 2010, workflow, office-365

I am building an SharePoint 2010 workflow in O365. I create a task in the workflow and assign it to someone. But how can I get the outcome of this task? I would like to implement an if statement for the outcome.